# MSTesthacks - Running in Continous Integration using Microsoft ALM not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mstest, tfsbuild, mstesthacks

I am using MSTest to run my unit test and for some reason, all the test are failing with the following error message

Unit Test Adapter threw exception:

**Data source 'XXX.YYY.DriverData.aboutThemContactInformationFlows' cannot be found in the test configuration settings..**

But the test are running fine in my local machine. Not sure whats going wrong.

I am having visual studio 2015 in my test machine as well in my dev machine.

The same setting is running fine in my dev machine.

Read other thread that points to missing app.config file in the test project. I do have a app.config file in the test project.

Is there any thing which I am missing. Below is the test settings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <TestSettings name="UITestSettings" id="1623gdcf4-f2af-496f-b65h4-fe25w6c4e49cb" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a remote test run.</Description>
  <Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="XXX\TestData\LocationData.xls" />
    <DeploymentItem filename="XXX\TestData\UITestData.xls" />
  </Deployment>
  <Execution parallelTestCount="0">
    <Timeouts runTimeout="36610000" testTimeout="36610000" />
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdcs9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccdfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
      <WebTestRunConfiguration testTypeId="4ess7599fa-5ecb-43e9-a887-cd63cfdf72d207">
        <Browser name="Internet Explorer 9.0" MaxConnections="6">
          <Headers>
            <Header name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)" />
            <Header name="Accept" value="*/*" />
            <Header name="Accept-Language" value="{{$IEAcceptLanguage}}" />
            <Header name="Accept-Encoding" value="GZIP" />
          </Headers>
        </Browser>
      </WebTestRunConfiguration>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="TestSettingsUIType" value="UnitTest" />
  </Properties>
</TestSettings>
```

Well, the dev machine is a Win10 machine and the test machine is also win 10 machine.

Help pls. Any information would be much much helpful

Comment: MSTesthacks is a unit test framework similar to MSTest but has more flexibility in passing data to the individual test. I use it to pass custom data source. Have  a look at https://github.com/Thwaitesy/MSTestHacks. It was really cool to use initially but...not now..

Comment: Ok, cool, I have created a new tag so that we can easily categorize questions with MSTestHacks in the future.

Comment: Which build you are using, Xaml or vNext?

Comment: vNext is what I am using

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not help you now, but I've just encountered the same problem with MSTestHacks and in my case, as in yours, I already had an app.config which is the suggested solution in various GitHub issues. I tracked it down to having made an assumption about the fully qualified namespace that you need in the `DataSource` attribute.

In my case I had assumed the namespace was

```
FrontOffice.BusinessLogicLayer.Tests.Queries.GenericTools.GetToolsForPartnerQueryTests.TestCases
```

This is because the project was named `FrontOffice.BusinessLogicLayer.Tests`. But when I checked the `Assembly name` and `Root namespace` fields in the project properties I discovered that they had been set as `FrontOffice.BusinessLogicLayerTests`.

Once I corrected this it ran as expected. It seems really obvious but check your namespaces carefully as unless you created them there's always a chance someone else did the (to my mind) stupid trick of having projects whose names do not match their namespaces.